# How to load a CSV string into MySQL using Python

Tags: python, mysql

In my use case, I have a csv stored as a string and I want to load it into a MySQL table. Is there a better way than saving the string as a file, use LOAD DATA INFILE, and then deleting the file? I find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627537/is-a-load-data-without-a-file-i-e-in-memory-possible-for-mysql-and-java) but it's for JDBC and I haven't find a Python equivalent to it.

Comment: Why not just put an insert stmt together ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes what you describe is very possible! Say, for example, that your csv file has three columns:

```
import MySQLdb
conn = MySQLdb.connect('your_connection_string')
cur = conn.cursor()
with open('yourfile.csv','rb') as fin:
    for row in fin:
        cur.execute('insert into yourtable (col1,col2,col3) values (%s,%s,%s)',row)
cur.close(); conn.close()
```

Comment: Will this be slow if I have many rows in my csv? I heard that LOAD DATA INFILE is more efficient when loading a large amount of data.