# How to allow LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE on mysql-connector-java?

Tags: java, mysql, mysql-connector

In the past I was using v5 of `mysql-connector-java` a lot. During `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE`, I usually set the connection to allow loading data from inmemory as follows:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.Connection con;
con.setAllowLoadLocalInfile(true);
```

Lateron it then set the file as inputstream directly for the database statement:

```
((com.mysql.jdbc.Statement) ps).setLocalInfileInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(...))
```

Now I'm migrating to version `8.0.13` of the connector, that the method does not exist anymore. Moreover, one has to use `java.sql.Connection` now.

How can I now set the property to allow load data on the connection explicit?

Especially as `java.sql.Statement` does not have the `.setLocalInfileInputStream()` method?

The developer guide even mentions that method, but does not tell how to get access to it:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-reference-implementation-notes.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is a "Load DATA" without a file (i.e., in memory) possible for MySQL and Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627537/is-a-load-data-without-a-file-i-e-in-memory-possible-for-mysql-and-java)

Answer (score 3):

This is how works for me:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tempDB?allowLoadLocalInfile=true
```

It is working for Mysql8.0.18

Answer (score 2):

The preferred method is to set the connection property `allowLoadLocalInfile=true` in the connection string and then call the method `setLocalInfileInputStream(InputStream stream)` from a Statement object cast to the interface `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.JdbcStatement`.

Comment: This worked with mysql-connector-java 8.0.17!
Keep in mind you may have to enable it on the server as well, see this SO thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10762239/mysql-enable-load-data-local-infile for my.cnf/my.ini flags

Answer (score 1):

At the end I switched to `mariadb` connector, which is a dropin replacement for `mysql`, but still has the localinfile method.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone comes looking at this the class needed moved.  It is now in `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl` at least in 8.0.15